# Create a "base" query, queryBuilder

Tags: php, laravel-4, query-builder

I have the feeling this is easy but I can't find the solution.

I have to create queries from many tables, but many of them has one table in common with same condition for that table, I had the "big" idea to create like a "basequery". this is the example.

```
$baseQuery = DB:: ('table')->where ('condition_in_common', 1);

$bar = $baseQuery->join ('bar', 'table_id', '=', 'table.id')
    ->where (myOwnConditions);

$foo = $baseQuery->join ('foo', 'table_id', '=', 'table.id')
    ->where (myOwnConditions);
```

What I expect is to have 2 queries, one for table "bar" and another for "foo"

```
select * from `table` inner join `bar` on `table`.`id` = `table_id` where condition_in_commom = 1 and myOwnConditions;

select * from `table` inner join `foo` on `table`.`id` = `table_id` where condition_in_commom = 1 and myOwnConditions;
```

But it doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this but you have to `clone` the query or you will always work with the same instance of the builder class:

```
$baseQuery = DB::table('table')->where('condition_in_common', 1);

$barQuery = clone $baseQuery;
$fooQuery = clone $fooQuery;

$bar = $barQuery->join('bar', 'table_id', '=', 'table.id')
                ->where(myOwnConditions)
                ->get();

$foo = $fooQuery->join('foo', 'table_id', '=', 'table.id')
                ->where(myOwnConditions)
                ->get();
```